# How can I remove all my Twitter favs?

Tags: twitter, twitter-favorites

I have tried to remove all my Twitter favorites but I can't.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Twitter Favs]

As you can see, I have 6 favorites but none of them appear.

Comment: seems like a caching bug from twitter

Comment: yes, I think it is a bug. Do you know where can I report this to Twitter?

Comment: You can report the bug here - https://support.twitter.com/forms/feature_report?feature=tweets not sure how much attention they will pay to it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a caching bug from Twitter - there's nothing much you can do except wait it out for a while.

Alternatively, you can report the bug to Twitter on their [support form](https://support.twitter.com/forms/feature_report?feature=tweets).

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com